# About Custom exception in java

Tags: java, exception

How can I create a custom exception in java without extending any built-in exception class?

Comment: I like this kind of questions `ASAP`. What you are willing to pay us?

Answer (score 7):

You can't. In Java, you can only `throw` a class that (eventually, somewhere down the line) extends `java.lang.Throwable`.